# openni_kinect install errors

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
When I try to install OpenNI to use the Kinect sensor, have the following errors:

The installation of OpenNI 1.52 works, but when I move to the Nite program I receive and error saying “Please install Open Ni 1.5.0.1”.
Further an error message tells me “The system has been modified”.
If anyone has any debugging suggestions, please let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58195/openni_kinect-install-errors/) by [meme](https://answers.ros.org/users/4426/meme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you've installed OpenNI 1.52 you might want to check your manifests.xml for the OpenNI packages in ROS and include the following:

---

Originally posted by [Rookdroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4073/rookdroid/) with karma: 76 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0